# What the function for header and plist file in framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I'm creating a new framework, the Xcode automatically create two files: one header file, and one plist file. For example:

[image]

I know what is header and plist. But, this files are important when my framework is a Swift pod for CocoaPod/Carthage/SPM? When this files are important?

Comment: did my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Anatomy of Framework Bundles

#### Framework Bundle Structure

> Framework bundles use a bundle structure different from the bundle
>   structure used by applications. The structure for frameworks is based
>   on an earlier bundle format, and allows for multiple versions of the
>   framework code and header files to be stored inside the bundle. This
>   type of bundle is known as a versioned bundle. Supporting multiple
>   versions of a framework allows older applications to continue running
>   even as the framework binary continues to evolve.
>
> The system identifies a framework by the .framework extension on its
>   directory name and by the Resources directory at the top level of the
>   framework bundle. **Inside the Resources directory is the Info.plist
>   file that contains the bundle’s identifying information.** The actual
>   Resources directory does not have to reside physically at the
>   top-level of the bundle. In fact, the system frameworks that come with
>   OS X have a symbolic link to the framework’s Resources directory in
>   this location. The link points to the most current version of the
>   Resources directory, buried somewhere inside the bundle.
>
> The contents of the Resources directory are similar to those for
>   application bundles. (See “Anatomy of a Modern Bundle” in Bundle
>   Programming Guide for more information.) Localized resources are put
>   in language-specific subdirectories that end with the .lproj
>   extension. These subdirectories hold strings, images, sounds, and
>   interface definitions localized to the language and region represented
>   by the directory. Nonlocalized resources reside at the top level of
>   the Resources directory.

#### Headers

> Contains any public headers you want to make available to external
>   developers.

[image]

For more information [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002253-BAJEJJAB) page.

### Cocoapods

If you'll publish your framework with [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org) for example, maybe better to start from [cocoapods's lib create guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html) instead of using XCode's scenario.

You can use this command to start (like guide says):

```
pod lib create MyLibrary
```

when you finnish framework create wizard you'll have directory tree like this :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I'm want to learning how to create a new framework manually. Then, I would like to understand these 2 files.

Comment: For example, the SwiftyJSON keep this files: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/master/Source But I don't understand why, if the CocoaPods, Carthage and SPM don't need it... as far as I know.

Comment: @Macabeus please check my updated answer. I answered for header and plist too now.

Comment: Yeah, thank you... But, the text does not say specifically about regarding CocoaPods/Carthage/SPM. For example, I need specify the version of my pod in plist, even that I can specify it in my `.podspec`?

Comment: Yes it's in podspec

Comment: Another question: if my pod is only-swift, why I need a header file? I can't understand why SwiftyJSON keep `SwiftyJSON.h`, for example. The OS need it when open the `.framework`?